# How to save the data of multiple rows of a html table using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created a table which adds new row dynamically. But I'm not able to the save the data. how to create separate each row data and how can I pass the data to the controller. Here is code.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
  <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col"> File</th>
                <th scope="col">Comments</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

             <tr ng-repeat="row in table.rows ">
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="rowdata.id"></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="rowdata.file"></td>

                <td><input type="text" ng-model="rowdata.Comments"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
              ng-click="addNewRow(table)">Add New Row</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
              ng-click = "saveData(rowdata)">Save changes</button>
```

controller.js

```
 .controller('homeController',function($scope){
$scope.table=[{name: "table 1"}];

    $scope.table.rows = [{name: "row 1"}];

    $scope.counter = 3;
$scope.addNewRow=function(table){
    table.rows.push({name: "row " + $scope.counter});
}

$scope.saveData=function(data){
    console.log(data);
    localStorage.setItem('data',data);

}
    })
```

Here when I click on save im getting undefined in console. I want the data in the rows to be passed. and once i click on save button data should be saves and it should reflect in table as a non editable fields.

Comment: There is no `rowdata` variable in your controller. `rowdata` is only created and populated in the view, *inside* the ng-repeat. So it's created in the scope created by ng-repeat, for each row. Not in the scope of your controller. You should have something like `ng-model="row.id"`, in order to populate each element of the `table.rows`array. Then you can access the data in the controller using `$scope.table.rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save `$scope.table.rows` in your controller, no need of passing `rowdata` (that doesn't exist) as parameter to your `$scope.saveData` function.

```
$scope.saveData = function(){
  localStorage.setItem('data', $scope.table.rows);
}
```

But if you prefer passing the table data as param it can look like:

template

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
  type="button"
  ng-click = "saveData(table.rows)">
  Save changes
</button>
```

controller

```
$scope.saveData = function(tableData){
  localStorage.setItem('data', tableData);
}
```